# Making both day-first and month-first dates in a csv file day-first

Tags: python, regex, csv, data-science

I have a csv file that has a column of dates. The dates are in order of month - so January comes first, then Feb, and so on. The problem is some of the dates are in mm/dd/yyyy format and others in dd/mm/yyyy format. Here's what it looks like.

Date

```
01/08/2005
01/12/2005
15/01/2005
19/01/2005
22/01/2005
26/01/2005
29/01/2005
03/02/2005
05/02/2005

...
```

I would like to bring all of them to the same format (dd/mm/yyyy)

I am using Python and pandas to read and edit the csv file. I tried using Excel to manually change the date formats using the built-in formatting tools but it seems impossible with the large number of rows. I'm thinking of using regex but I'm not quite sure how to distinguish between month-first and day-first.

```
# here's what i have so far
date = df.loc[i, 'Date']

pattern = r'\d\d/\d\d/\d\d'        
match = re.search(pattern, date)  

if match:
    date_items = date.split('/')
    day = date_items[1]
    month = date_items[0]
    year = date_items[2]
    new_date = f'{dd}/{mm}/{year}'
    df.loc[i, 'Date'] = new_date
```

I want the csv to have a uniform date format in the end.

Answer (score 1):

In short: you can't!

There's no way for you to know if 01/02/2019 is Jan 2nd or Feb 1st!
Same goes for other dates in your examples such as:

```
01/08/2005
01/12/2005
03/02/2005
05/02/2005
```

Comment: Knowing the months are ordered, maybe?

Comment: You can probably disambiguate based on context, but the logic certainly isn't straightforward and may require backtracking in some instances, and even still you might end up with corner cases you can't resolve (if the context isn't sufficient).

Comment: Can we use the fact that they are in order of month? The first date is always in January.

Comment: @L.B. Interesting thought, but if you have 1/2/2019 and then 2/1/2019, 3/1/2019 - even though they're sorted in chronicle order - you still can't tell each one of them if it's Jan or Feb.